# How to produce horizontal overlap in align environments?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I have a reoccuring issue when aligning equations, namely that I want a pattern like this:

```
xxx x xxx
    x xxx
    x xxx
x xxxxx
```

Example:

```
\renewcommand{\d}{\bm{d}}
\newcommand*{\deriv}[2]{\dfrac{\d#1}{\d#2}} 
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\d fg &= (f + \d f)(g + \d g) - fg\\
      &= fg + f \d g + \d f g - fg\\
      &= f \d g + \d f g \\
\implies \deriv{fg}{x} = f \deriv{g}{x} + g \deriv{g}{x}
\end{alignat*}
```

Which turns out as

[image]

corresponding to something like this

```
    xxx x xxx
        x xxx
        x xxx
x xxxxx
```

How could I align a line such as the last one in the example, with the first line without the cells in the lines above being pushed further to the right, because the last lien extends further than the first line's part before the alignment separator?

Comment: please edit your example so it can be used to reproduce the image shown, and used as a test file for possible answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `aligned` nested in `align`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}
\newcommand{\deriv}[2]{\frac{\diff #1}{\diff #2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&\begin{aligned}
\diff(fg) &= (f + \diff f)(g + \diff g) - fg\\
         &= fg + f(\diff g) + (\diff f) g - fg\\
         &= f (\diff g) + (\diff f) g
\end{aligned}
\\
&\negthickspace\negmedspace
\implies \deriv{(fg)}{x} = f \deriv{g}{x} + g \deriv{g}{x}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

<sub>The math is nonsense, sorry.</sub>

Avoid redefining `\d`.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I had in mind! The math is not nonsense though... if I did not misspell something that I am overlooking. It's Leibniz argument for the product rule, including df * dg being "negligible" compared to the other terms and thus 'falling off the table'. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule#Discovery

Comment: @lotolmencre It's nonsense anyway, which doesn't lessen my opinion and admiration on Leibniz. `;-)`

Comment: You mean there is something wrong with the original proof?

Comment: @lotolmencre The idea is correct, the arguments aren't (see Robinson's Nonstandard Analysis for a really rigorous approach to infinitesimals).

Comment: why not use `gather` with a nested `aligned` for the first three lines?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Because the OP seemed to want global left alignment.

Answer (score 1):

Not very clear, but maybe this is what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\renewcommand*{\d}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\usepackage{esdiff}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
   & \d fg & & = (f + \d f)(g + \d g) - fg \\
   & & & = fg + f \d g + \d f g - fg \\
   & & & = f \d g + \d f g \\[1ex]
   & \mathrlap{\implies \diff{fg}{x} = f \diff{g}{x} + g \diff{g}{x}}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]